# How do i upload an CSV file to Google Cloud Storage, using nodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I need to upload and share my documents using Google Cloud and nodeJS but I'm not sure how to do it exactly.

Comment: The best way consists in using [@google-cloud/storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage) NPM library. This allows to upload or download files (among other operations). There are good code samples in the official documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to check the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-storage) and to find out more about Google Cloud Storage and how to upload your files or documents to Google Cloud Storage.

Regarding uploading a CSV file to Google Cloud Storage, you can access this [link](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-storage) where you can use different ways to upload files to Google Cloud Storage.

For your case use, here is the code sample to upload a file using nodeJS. Here in your case just change in the const field for the filename to the path of your file and instead of .txt you should specify .csv.

```
/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
 */
// const bucketName = 'Name of a bucket, e.g. my-bucket';
// const filename = 'Local file to upload, e.g. ./local/path/to/file.txt';

// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();

async function uploadFile() {
  // Uploads a local file to the bucket
  await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filename, {
    // Support for HTTP requests made with `Accept-Encoding: gzip`
    gzip: true,
    // By setting the option `destination`, you can change the name of the
    // object you are uploading to a bucket.
    metadata: {
      // Enable long-lived HTTP caching headers
      // Use only if the contents of the file will never change
      // (If the contents will change, use cacheControl: 'no-cache')
      cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
    },
  });

  console.log(`${filename} uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
}

uploadFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this GitHub repository its has [examples](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/samples/uploadFile.js) for cloud storage with Nodejs